# Object-oriented models and backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, value-objects

Suppose I'm working with an API which returns JSON data, but which has a complex or variable structure. For example, a string-valued property may be a plain literal, or may be tagged with a language:

```
/* first pattern */
{ "id": 1,
  "label": "a foo"
}

/* second pattern */
{ "id": 2,
  "label": [ {"value": "a foo", "lang": "en"},
             {"value": "un foo", "lang": "fr"}]
}
```

In my client-side code, I don't want to have view code worrying about whether a label is available in multiple-languages, and which one to pick, etc. Or I might want to hide the detailed JSON structure for other reasons. So, I might wrap the JSON value in an object with a suitable API:

```
/** Value object for foo instances sent from server */
var Foo = function( json ) {
  this.json = json;
};

/** Return a suitable label for this foo object */
Foo.prototype.label = function() {
  var i18n = ... ;
  if (i18n.prefLang && _.isArray(this.json.label)) // ... etc etc
};
```

So this is all pretty normal [value-object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object), and it's helpful because it's more decoupled from the specific JSON structure, more testable, etc. OK good.

What I currently don't see a way around is how to use one of these value objects with Backbone and Marionette. Specifically, I'd like to use a `Foo` object as the basis for a Backbone `Model`, and bind it to a Marionette `ItemView`. However, as far as I can see, the values in a `Model` are taken directly from the JSON structure - I can't see a way to recognise that the objects are functions:

```
var modelFoo = new Backbone.Model( foo );
> undefined
modelFoo.get( "label" ).constructor
> function Function() { [native code] }
```

So my question is: what is a good way to decouple the attributes of a Backbone `Model` from the specifics of a given JSON structure, such as a complex API value? Can value objects, models and views be made to play nice?

**Edit**

Let me add one more example, as I think the example above focussing on i18n issues only conveys part of my concern. Simplifying somewhat, in my domain, I have waterbodies comprising rivers, lakes and inter-tidal zones. A  waterbody has associated with it one or more sampling points, and each sampling point has a latest sample. This might come back from the data API on the server as something like:

```
{"id": "GB12345678",
 "centre": {"lat": 1.2345, "long": "-2.3456"},
 "type": "river",
 "samplingPoints": [{"id": "sp98765",
                     "latestSample": {"date": "20130807", 
                                      "classification": "normal"}
                    }]
}
```

So in my view code, I *could* write expressions such as:

```
<%= waterbody.samplingPoints[0].latestSample.classification %>
```

or

```
<% if (waterbody.type === "river") { %>
```

but that would be horrible, and easily broken if the API format changes.  Slightly better, I could abstract such manipulations out into template helper functions, but they are still hard to write tests for. What I'd like to do is have a value object class `Waterbody`, so that my view code can have something like:

```
<%= waterbody.latestClassification() %>
```

One of the main problems I'm finding with Marionette is the insistence on calling `toJSON()` on the models passed to views, but perhaps some of the computed property suggestions have a way of getting around that.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the use for `serializeData` in a model. You can manipulate the model any way you see fit for the view there.

Comment: updated my answer to respond on your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest solution IMO is to put the label accessor into the model instead of the VO:

```
var FooModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    getLabel : function(){
        return this.getLocalized("label");
    },
    getLocalized : function(key){
        //return correct value from "label" array
    }
});
```

and let the views use `FooModel#getLabel` instead of `FooModel#get("label")`

--EDIT 1

This lib seems interesting for your use case as well: [Backbone.Schema](https://github.com/DreamTheater/Backbone.Schema)

It allows you to formally declare the type of your model's attributes, but also provides some syntax sugar for localized strings and allows you to create dynamic attributes (called 'computed properties'), composed from the values of other attributes.

--EDIT 2 (in response to the edited question)

IMO the VO returned from the server should be wrapped inside a model and this model is passed to the view. The model implements `latestClassification`, not the VO, this allows the view to directly call that method on the model.

Comment: Backbone.Schema does look interesting, thanks for the pointer. I've updated the question to clarify some of my other concerns that lie behind the question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to this (possibly to simple for your implementation) would be to override the model's `parse` method to return suitable attributes:

```
var modelFoo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function ( json ) {
        var i18n = ... ;
        if (i18n.prefLang && _.isArray(json.label)) {
            // json.label = "complex structure"
        }
        return json;
    }
});
```

That way only your model worries about how the data from the server is formatted without adding another layer of abstraction.

Comment: So treat is as a kind of facade pattern. OK, I can see that. In the case of the i18n labels, throwing away the non-preferred language labels would mean that if the user switches languages in the UI I would have to ask the server to resend the data. But yes, if the mapping from server data to presentation form is static, this would be a possible tactic.

Comment: @IanDickinson you could always move the original label to another property. like `json.labels = json.label; json.label = "complex value";` and if `json.label` is not an array, you can just add it to the json using `json.labels = [json.label]` and create a consistent API for that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the question to expand on my underlying concern.